# Error after deleting logo.svg file in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, svg

In general after creating a project using creat-react-app, there is a file included named logo.svg . I don't want to use react's logo in my project. So that i deleted this file from my project.
But after deletion it shows an error ! Screenshot is attached bellow - 
[Screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B5MDQ.png)

Why it happens ? Is there any way to solve this issue ?
It shows to open a directory 
***D:\React\cafe-4-4-2\node_modules\react-scripts\config\polyfills.js*** ; but there is no derectory named react-scripts under the node_modules !

> I tried(delete logo.svg) to delete this file in 3 different projects, every time it shows the
>   same error !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Deleting the 'logo.svg' file wouldn't cause this error.  But if you delete the logo you shouldn't forget to remove the following lines.

```
import logo from './logo.svg'
```

and remove
The image tag as well

```
<img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
```

Or you can replace them with your own logo.

Comment: I did it , i removed import statement and obviously the <img> tag , But it still shows the error !

Comment: you could try removing your `node_modules` folder and running `npm` `install`.